# VLC Player shows broken HLS stream with 4k HDR10 mkv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, vlc

I am trying to convert a 4k mkv to an HLS stream but I am not having any luck. I have tried a few ffmpeg commands to try and fix the issue but none have worked. Here are the commands I have tried.

1. Basic copy command:

`ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" -c copy -f hls "plexTemp/out.m3u8"`

2. Command used to see if it was an HDR color issue:

`ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -f hls "plexTemp/out.m3u8"`
3. Command used to revert to 8 bit color:

`ffmpeg -i "video.mkv" -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -f hls "plexTemp/out.m3u8"`

4. I tried removing extra streams and just focusing on audio and video:

`ffmpeg -i "out.mkv" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -f hls "plexTemp/out.m3u8"`

I also saw these warnings when running each command.`Stream HEVC is not hvc1, you should use tag:v hvc1 to set it.`
And this

```
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Stream #12: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 7 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 8 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 9 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 10 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 000001d7921803c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 11 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
```

So I tried increasing the `analyzeduration` and `probesize` and adding the tag like so:
`ffmpeg -analyzeduration 10000000 -probesize 10000000 -i "out.mkv" -c copy -tag:v hvc1 -f hls "plexTemp/out.m3u8"`

To no avail. Here is what the output looks like on VLC. It's mostly black with a few lines of color that randomly change.[image]

On my TV I see this:

[image]

One thing I see that stands out in ffmpegs output is this:

```
[hls @ 00000207239a9ec0] Opening 'plexTemp/out0.ts' for writing7 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[hls @ 00000207239a9ec0] Opening 'plexTemp/out.m3u8.tmp' for writing
```

Here is the audio and video info on the mkv:

```
General
Unique ID                                : 92280908398971492516286250889389584022 (0x456CA80EF29B1357B572719D6EC4AE96)
Complete name                            : I:\video.mkv
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 2
File size                                : 49.4 GiB
Duration                                 : 1 h 39 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 71.2 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
Movie name                               : video
Encoded date                             : 2023-04-06 22:39:53 UTC
Writing application                      : MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
Writing library                          : libmakemkv v1.16.7 (1.3.10/1.5.2) win(x64-release)
Cover                                    : Yes
Attachments                              : cover.jpg

Video
ID                                       : 1
ID in the original source medium         : 4113 (0x1011)
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5.1@High
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2086, HDR10 compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 1 h 39 min
Bit rate                                 : 63.6 Mb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0 (Type 2)
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.320
Stream size                              : 44.1 GiB (89%)
Writing library                          : ATEME Titan File 3.9.6 (4.9.6.2)        
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : Display P3
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0050 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 140 cd/m2
Original source medium                   : Blu-ray

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
ID in the original source medium         : 4352 (0x1100)
Format                                   : DTS XLL X
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Commercial name                          : DTS:X
Codec ID                                 : A_DTS
Duration                                 : 1 h 39 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 4 174 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 8 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R LFE Lb Rb Lss Rss
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 93.750 FPS (512 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 2.89 GiB (6%)
Title                                    : Surround 7.1
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Original source medium                   : Blu-ray
Here is information on the HLS output:
General
Complete name                            : I:\out.m3u8
Format                                   : HLS
Format profile                           : Media
File size                                : 67.4 MiB
Duration                                 : 8 s 138 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 69.4 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
```

And my
Here is the output of my HLS stream:

```
Video
ID                                       : 256 (0x100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5.1@High
HDR format                               : SMPTE ST 2086, HDR10 compatible
Muxing mode                              : MPEG-TS
Codec ID                                 : 36
Duration                                 : 8 s 49 ms
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0 (Type 2)
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Writing library                          : ATEME Titan File 3.9.6 (4.9.6.2)        
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.2020
Transfer characteristics                 : PQ
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.2020 non-constant
Mastering display color primaries        : Display P3
Mastering display luminance              : min: 0.0050 cd/m2, max: 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Content Light Level              : 1000 cd/m2
Maximum Frame-Average Light Level        : 140 cd/m2
Source                                   : out92.ts

Audio
ID                                       : 257 (0x101)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : DTS XLL X
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Commercial name                          : DTS:X
Muxing mode                              : MPEG-TS
Codec ID                                 : 130
Duration                                 : 8 s 138 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Channel(s)                               : 8 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R LFE Lb Rb Lss Rss
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 93.750 FPS (512 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Delay relative to video                  : -125 ms
Language                                 : English
Source                                   : out92.ts
```